# nth Fibonacci number, recursive ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, fibonacci

**Edit:**
I stored r12 in the stack and retrieved it whenever I needed it and the problem was fixed.

I want to return the nth Fibonacci number; I also have the C code and output both values , C code is working fine but the assembly code has problem which I can't find, I already tried gdb but I couldn't understand the problem, here is my code:

```
.global fib_rec_s


fib_rec_s:
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str lr, [sp]
    cmp r0, #0   // if n = 0 exit
    beq exit
    cmp r0, #1   //if n = 1 exit
    bne rec_step //else branch to rec_step
    b exit

rec_step:
    str r0, [sp, #4]   // store n in the stack
    sub r0, r0, #1     // n-1
    bl fib_rec_s       // f(n-1)
    mov r12, r0        // store f(n-1) in r12
    ldr r0, [sp,#4]    // retrieve n from the stack
    sub r0, r0, #2     // n-2
    bl fib_rec_s       // f(n-2)
    add r0 ,r0 , r12   //f(n-1) + f(n-2)


exit:
    ldr lr, [sp]
    add sp, sp, #8
    bx lr
```

Here is the output i get from the test:

```
./fib fib_rec 0

fib_rec_c(0) = 0 // output from C
fib_rec_s(0) = 0 // output from assembly

./fib fib_rec 1
fib_rec_c(1) = 1
fib_rec_s(1) = 1

./fib fib_rec 2
fib_rec_c(2) = 1
fib_rec_s(2) = 1

./fib fib_rec 3
fib_rec_c(3) = 2
fib_rec_s(3) = 2

./fib fib_rec 4
fib_rec_c(4) = 3
fib_rec_s(4) = 2

./fib fib_rec 5
fib_rec_c(5) = 5
fib_rec_s(5) = 3

./fib fib_rec 6
fib_rec_c(6) = 8
fib_rec_s(6) = 3

./fib fib_rec 7
fib_rec_c(7) = 13
fib_rec_s(7) = 4

./fib fib_rec 8
fib_rec_c(8) = 21
fib_rec_s(8) = 4
```

The output is not correct for number > 3. I can not find the problem.

I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi Zero.

Comment: Finding the error in your code would be a lot easier if you had commented your code with what you think the instructions d.

Comment: Your [mcve] is missing details on what results you *do* get.  That's a necessary part of a question if you want people to help debug it for you by looking at the code.  Also, use a debugger (like GDB) to single-step your asm and look at register values.

Comment: It looks like you expect R12 to be preserved across the first `bl fib_rec_s`, but your function just destroys it without saving/restoring it.

Comment: @Patricia Cool!

Comment: @peter I added the output

Comment: @Patricia Instead of "edit: problem fixed" in the question, the preferred approach is a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).